# Query Azure RBAC assignments using Azure powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, rbac

Azure: Extend Psh command with two columns resource type & name

I am trying to write a Azure Psh command with two columns resource type & name and query the RBAC assignments for a user.
I have these two tables, is there a way to merge the following two tables?
Following is my current progress with the command:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName A12345@abc.com | Select-Object -Property RoleDefinitionName, {Get-AzResource -ResourceId $_.RoleAssignmentID | Select-Object -Property Name,ResourceType} | Format-Table;
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName A12345@abc.com | Select-Object -Property RoleDefinitionName, {Get-AzResource -ResourceId $_.Scope | Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceType} | Format-Table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use the below command to directly get the two information in one line :***

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName ansuman@xyz.com | Select-Object -Property RoleDefinitionName, {Get-AzResource -ResourceId $_.RoleAssignmentID | Select-Object -Property Name,ResourceType} , {Get-AzResource -ResourceId $_.Scope | Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceType} | Format-Table
```

**Update:**

***To prettify the Headers you can use this :***

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName ans@xyz.com | Select-Object -Property RoleDefinitionName, @{N='RoleDetails';E={Get-AzResource -ResourceId $_.RoleAssignmentID | Select-Object -Property Name,ResourceType}} , @{L='ScopeDetails';E={Get-AzResource -ResourceId $_.Scope | Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceType}}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks :) How do I rename the column names here as they look ugly.
I have tried the following and returns me an empty table:
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName T20821@eon.com | Select-Object -Property RoleDefinitionName, {Get-AzResource -ResourceId $_.RoleAssignmentID | Select-Object -Property Name,ResourceType} | Format-Table @{L='Roles';E={RoleDefinitionName}},@{L='ResourceType';E={Get-AzResource -ResourceId $_.RoleAssignmentID | Select-Object -Property Name,ResourceType}}